# How can I mirror a gameobject movement in Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, position, mirror

I have two gameobjects and I want them to be placed butt on butt just like in the picture, but I want them to move and rotate together so that they will always be placed like that. I am controlling the black object so I just used`transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, player.transform.eulerAngles.z + 180);` in order to get the right rotation, but I just can't get the position right. Here is a sketch of how I want them to be placed.[image: Visual explanation of the positions]

When moving my black object in a direction, the two gameobjects do not remain attached. Here is a representation of the problem.[image: Problem]

Here you have my exact script and photo:
Script that I use for moving the ai:

`transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(0, player.transform.localScale.y + transform.localScale.y - 1, 0);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, player.transform.eulerAngles.z + 180);
            transform.parent = player.transform;`

And the exact photo in the Inspector:[image]

And this is how I want them to be placed at all the time:https://bugguide.net/images/cache/SL2/ZZL/SL2ZZLPZMLOH6HHRUHRREHVH7HVHZLWZLL6Z7H6Z8H5Z7HEZ5LEZ5H8ZSLAHRL2Z4LBZ7LAZILAZXLGZKL2ZMHAHMH.jpg

[UPDATE] I used @Ali Kanat 's answer and I'm halfway there:[image: Update]
As you can see in the picture the two bugs are now one over the other but they are moving together as they should.

Comment: There is clearly a problem with the scalse. Just don't divide it to 2 it must solve the problem.

Comment: Also i believe you are in 2D so instead of `forward` you should use `up` as far as i can understand from your image

Comment: That's right! And one more thing transform.right=(-player.transform.right) not forward

Comment: Okay as i said it depends on your sprite you know it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make red object(or any other objects you have) a child of black object and rotate black object. This way you can preserve the geometry and you do not have to modify `transform`component of the other objects.

After the comments i am assuming the big lady bug is the `Player`. To achieve what you want programmatically can be like this:

```
//forward, up or right depends on which direction is the front of your player
transform.position = player.transform.position + ((-player.transform.forward) * (player.transform.localScale.y
        + transform.localScale.y)/2);
transform.forward = (-player.transform.forward);
```

Because what you want to achieve is to find the position which is (PlayersizeY + enemySizeY) away in direction of back of the Player. This will work no matter what your Player`s orientation is.

Comment: Yes, but that only makes it rotate the way I like. The position is still off and every time my black object moves, they are not alligned. I will give another representation in my question.@Ali Kanat

Comment: I am not sure if i understand correctly but if black is the parent of red, rotation or translation does not matter they will always be attached when you move black one only. If you move red one of course it will not work. You just have to modify black object's Transform.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but my two objects are already moving together. They just always have this 'gap' between them.

Comment: Can you share a screen shot of your inspector and your script with which you move them?

Comment: check the question. How I want them to be: https://bugguide.net/images/cache/SL2/ZZL/SL2ZZLPZMLOH6HHRUHRREHVH7HVHZLWZLL6Z7H6Z8H5Z7HEZ5LEZ5H8ZSLAHRL2Z4LBZ7LAZILAZXLGZKL2ZMHAHMH.jpg

Comment: So this is an ai and they are not initially back to back you want them to be back to back like in the image above after some time? I dont get it why do not you make them back to back in the inspector and apply my answer.

Comment: I am trying to do that through script as I have objects of different sizes.@Ali Kanat

Comment: Updated question @Ali Kanat